# Reverse the legend order when using ggplotly()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I would like to reverse the order of the legend for a horizontal bar chart. When adding `guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))` to the `ggplot` it works fine (see second plot). However, after applying `ggplotly()` the legend is again in the default order.

How to reverse the order of the `plotly` legend **without** changing the order of the bars?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)

p1 <- mtcars %>%
  count(cyl, am) %>%
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl), am = factor(am)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(cyl, n, fill = am)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip()
p1
```

[image]

```r
p2 <- p1 + guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
p2
```

[image]

```r
plotly::ggplotly(p2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call ggplotly, it's really just creating a list and a function call on that list.

So if you save that intermediate step, you can modify the list directly. and as such, modify the plot output.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)

p1 <- mtcars %>%
  count(cyl, am) %>%
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl), am = factor(am)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(cyl, n, fill = am)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip()

html_plot <- ggplotly(p1)

replace_1 <- html_plot[["x"]][["data"]][[2]]
replace_2 <- html_plot[["x"]][["data"]][[1]]
html_plot[["x"]][["data"]][[1]] <- replace_1
html_plot[["x"]][["data"]][[2]] <- replace_2

html_plot
```

[plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quKxG.png)

Comment: What is `x` in this case?

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the great answer of @Zac Garland here is a solution that works with legends of arbitrary length:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

reverse_legend_labels <- function(plotly_plot) {
  n_labels <- length(plotly_plot$x$data)
  plotly_plot$x$data[1:n_labels] <- plotly_plot$x$data[n_labels:1]
  plotly_plot
}

p1 <- mtcars %>%
  count(cyl, am) %>%
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl), am = factor(am)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(cyl, n, fill = am)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip()

p2 <- mtcars %>%
  count(am, cyl) %>%
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl), am = factor(am)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(am, n, fill = cyl)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip()
```

```r
p1 %>%
  plotly::ggplotly() %>%
  reverse_legend_labels()
```

[image]

```r
p2 %>%
  plotly::ggplotly() %>%
  reverse_legend_labels()
```

[image]

Comment: What is `x` in this case?

Comment: Also, can you please add some explanation as to what the `reverse_legend_labels` function is doing?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to define the order of the levels of the factor variable `am`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)


df <-  mtcars %>%
  count(cyl, am) %>%
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl), am = factor(as.character(am), levels = c("1", "0"))) 

head(df)


p1 <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(cyl, n, fill = am)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip()
p1
```

[image]

```
plotly::ggplotly(p1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Rami Krispin! What I am trying to achieve though is that the color of the upper bar matches the color of the upper legend. Here this issue remains. The upper bar is green but the upper legend is orange.