# R ggplot2 geom_bar change/flip order of legend items

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

Based on the data and code below, how can I change of the legend items such that the legend item `Males` is under the `Male portion` of the `pyramid plot` and vice versa?

I tried:

```
# Change the order of values to reflect them in the plot
  pop_hisp_df$Type = factor(pop_hisp_df$Type, levels = rev(pop_hisp_df$Type))

Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : 
  factor level [2] is duplicated
```

Current Output:

[image]

Data (`pop_hisp_df`):

```
structure(list(age_group = c("<  5 years", "5 - 14", "15  -  24", 
"25  -  34", "35  -  44", "45  -  54", "55  -  64", "65  -  74", 
"75  -  84", "85 +", "<  5 years", "5 - 14", "15  -  24", "25  -  34", 
"35  -  44", "45  -  54", "55  -  64", "65  -  74", "75  -  84", 
"85 +"), Type = c("Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", 
"Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", "Males", "Females", "Females", 
"Females", "Females", "Females", "Females", "Females", "Females", 
"Females", "Females"), Value = c(-6, -13, -13, -15, -17, -15, 
-11, -6, -3, -1, 6, 12, 12, 14, 16, 15, 12, 7, 4, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

# Plot
    gg_pop_hisp = ggplot(pop_hisp_df, aes( x = forcats::as_factor(age_group), y = Value, fill = Type)) +
      geom_bar(data = subset(pop_hisp_df, Type == "Females"), stat = "identity") +
      geom_bar(data = subset(pop_hisp_df, Type == "Males"), stat = "identity") +
      #geom_text(aes(label = paste0(abs(Value), "%"))) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-20,20),
                         breaks=c(-15,-10,0,10,15),
                         labels=paste0(c(15,10,0,10,15),"%")) +          # CHANGE
      scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("Females"="#FC921F", "Males"="#149ECE"), labels = c("Females", "Males")) +
      ggtitle("HISPANIC POPULATION BY GENDER AND AGE GROUP") +
      labs(x = "AGE GROUPS", y = "PERCENTAGE POPULATION", fill = "Gender") +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(legend.position="bottom") +
      coord_flip()  
    
    # Interactive
    ggplotly(gg_pop_hisp) %>% 
      layout(
        legend = list(
          orientation = 'h', x = 0.3, y = -0.3, 
          title = list(text = '')))
```

Comment: The second answer to [Reverse the legend order when using ggplotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59611914/reverse-the-legend-order-when-using-ggplotly) solves the problem. However, it would have been helpful if the answer had some explanation as to what the `reverse_legend_labels` function is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution for ggplotly Only

In this case, simply swapping the calls to `geom_bar` (i.e create bars for Males at first and then for Females) creates the desired output, which is a lot simpler.

---

```
gg_pop_hisp = ggplot(pop_hisp_df, aes( x = forcats::as_factor(age_group), y = Value, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(data = subset(pop_hisp_df, Type == "Males"), stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(data = subset(pop_hisp_df, Type == "Females"), stat = "identity") +
  #geom_text(aes(label = paste0(abs(Value), "%"))) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-20,20),
                     breaks=c(-15,-10,0,10,15),
                     labels=paste0(c(15,10,0,10,15),"%")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("Females"="#FC921F", "Males"="#149ECE"), labels = c("Females", "Males")) +
  ggtitle("HISPANIC POPULATION BY GENDER AND AGE GROUP") +
  labs(x = "AGE GROUPS", y = "PERCENTAGE POPULATION", fill = "Gender") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  coord_flip()

gg_pop_hisp

# Interactive
ggplotly(gg_pop_hisp) %>% 
  layout(
    legend = list(
      orientation = 'h', x = 0.3, y = -0.3, 
      title = list(text = '')))
```

**ggplotly Output**

[image: ggplotly_output]

Its works because, the bar for `Males` are created at first, so the legend is and similarly thereafter for `Females` and therefore, `ggplotly` renders the legend in this order.

---

### Solution for both ggplot2 and ggplotly

**Note that**, in the intermediate `ggplot` plot `gg_pop_hisp` the issue of misplaced legend still remains. To solve this case both for `ggplot` and `ggplotly` output,

Create factor variable `labels` with levels as `Levels: Males Females` and use that `scale_fill_manual` to specify the `labels` of the scale and also change the order of `values`.

---

```
labels = forcats::as_factor(c("Males", "Females"))

gg_pop_hisp = ggplot(pop_hisp_df, aes( x = forcats::as_factor(age_group), y = Value, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(data = subset(pop_hisp_df, Type == "Males"), stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(data = subset(pop_hisp_df, Type == "Females"), stat = "identity") +
  #geom_text(aes(label = paste0(abs(Value), "%"))) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-20,20),
                     breaks=c(-15,-10,0,10,15),
                     labels=paste0(c(15,10,0,10,15),"%")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("Males"="#149ECE", "Females"="#FC921F"), # awapped the order here
                    labels = labels) +
  ggtitle("HISPANIC POPULATION BY GENDER AND AGE GROUP") +
  labs(x = "AGE GROUPS", y = "PERCENTAGE POPULATION", fill = "Gender") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  coord_flip()
```

---

**ggplot2 output**

```
gg_pop_hisp
```

[image: ggplot_output]

---

and the **ggplotly output** in this case,

```
ggplotly(gg_pop_hisp) %>% 
  layout(
    legend = list(
      orientation = 'h', x = 0.3, y = -0.3, 
      title = list(text = '')))
```

[image: ggplotly_output]

---